# Using AFNetworking (AFHTTPClient subclass) to send JSON to server => is this an asynchronous operation

Tags: ios, json, asynchronous, afnetworking

So after much research I figured out how to send a `NSDictionary` from my iOS 6 client to my rails server. I used `AFNetworking`. Below is the client side code that sends the JSON. However, Im not sure if this is an asynchronous call since I dont see where an operation queue is being used. If it isn't then how do I make it into an asynchronous call?

```
  -(void)sendEntryToServerAsJSON:(EntryParent*)_entryToBeSaved
  {
     NSDictionary* dictToBeSerialized = [_entryToBeSaved convertEntryParentObjToDict];


     [[appAPIClient sharedClient]postPath:@"entries.json"
                          parameters:dictToBeSerialized
                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"Successfully sent JSON %@", [responseObject description]);
      }
                             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)    {
       NSLog(@"Could not send JSON %@", [error description]);
      }];
  }
```

Here is my implementation of the AFHTTPClient

```
 + (appAPIClient *)sharedClient
 {
   NSLog(@"Inside appAPIClient sharedclient ");
   static appAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
   dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
    _sharedClient = [[self alloc]
                     initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_STR]];
  });

   return _sharedClient;
 }
 //==============================================================================

 - (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
 {
   self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
   if (!self)
  {
    return nil;
   }
   NSLog(@"init with base url - appAPIClient");
   [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

   // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

   return self;
}
```

---

I would appreciate any feedback to improve this code and make it asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to a)

the requests are added to the main threads runloop so they are async without a thread or queue. runloops are kinda like C's select method

see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html

to b) please make into a separate question :)

Comment: I looked into the library of AFNetworking and it seems the AFHTTPClient uses a NSOperation queue for this method under the hood.So would this method tie up my main thread while its sending?

Comment: well it does use NSOperations to manage stuff and do everything not networking specific. (e.g. parsing JSON). the networking itself though is done via the main runloop so it doesn't burn threads. it is all async :)